# Format the JTable as shown in Text File?

Tags: java, swing, text, jtable

Hi i am reading a text file into `JTable`, but here is what my JTable Looks Like Now: 
[image]

How can I format it correctly and allow `JTable` to be editable by users?

My Text File: File Name(people.txt)

```
COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_TYPE IS_NULLABLE COLUMN_KEY  COLUMN_DEFAULT  EXTRA   
Names   VARCHAR(500)    NO  
Address VARCHAR(500)    NO
```

Coding so far:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.table.*;

   public class stackq extends AbstractTableModel {
    Vector data;
    Vector columns;

    public stackq() {
            String line;
            data = new Vector();
            columns = new Vector();
            try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/joy/text/people.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");
                    while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                            columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                            while (st2.hasMoreTokens())
                                    data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                    }
                    br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size() / getColumnCount();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
                            + columnIndex);
    }

     public String getColumnName(int i){
         return (String)columns.get(i);
              }


      public static void main(String s[]) {
            stackq model = new stackq();
            JTable table = new JTable();
            table.setModel(model);
           JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(scrollpane);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(panel, "Center");
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      }
```

Thank You So much.

Comment: Interestingly, when I copy/paste that text content as a String into the source and run it, I get a quite different result than seen above - with distinct columns.  Are the values in the original file separated by spaces or a tab character or something else?

Comment: COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_TYPE IS_NULLABLE COLUMN_KEY COLUMN_DEFAULT EXTRA 
Names VARCHAR(500) NO 
Address VARCHAR(500) NO

Comment: hi andrew , copy the above to source text now and run, this will work now

Comment: @your pictures looks very strange, just like @Andrew said. If you want table to be editable, you can use `table.setCellEditable(true)` and register a `Table Cell Listener` to table, after stopping editing, you can call `setValueAt()` to set the new value to table model, you can google for it.

Comment: *"..this will work now"*  No, it won't since my system does not have a file at `D:/joy/text/people.txt`.  Why do you think I turned the data to a `String` in the 1st place?  Also, when I ask a question, answer it.  I ask these questions for *your* benefit, in order to try and progress towards a solution, rather than to hear myself talk.

Comment: hi Andrew, sorry for that, by the way the values are separated by TAB

Comment: @tim don't you think that you should then use a `new StringTokenizer(line, "\t")`? You specify the white space as being the separator of your columns while it is actually tabs, so the tokenizer will return the whole line as a single token.

Comment: oh thank you so much Guillanume Polet, new StringTokenizer(line, "\t"), works fine now all my data's are separated, do you know how can i edit my cell's in table and update it

Comment: @tim override `isCellEditable` and `setValueAt` in your `AbstractTableModel`

Comment: @Guillanume Polet i did this as you said, but i get this error Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true ;
    }

    Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
            Vector rowVector = (Vector) data.elementAt(row);
            rowVector.setElementAt(aValue, column);
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
        }
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
        at Stackq.setValueAt(Stackq.java:49)

Comment: hi i have posted my new question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056222/update-the-jtable-at-runtime  , ok how to give points for you ? i dont see any green tick mark near you @Guillanume Polet

Answer (score 1):

```
public Stackq() {
String line;
data = new Vector();
columns = new Vector();
int count = 0;
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\1.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");
    while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
    columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());
    count++;
    }
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (st2.hasMoreTokens())
        data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
        else
        data.addElement("");
    }
    }
    br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Just add one count variable for header count, and add the empty string into the data vector where tokenizer returns null.

Comment: hi, i did run your code, but still it shows the same : http://imagesup.net/?di=713661785967

Comment: hi that is so good to see, i have made the edit , have look at my whole code: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=KIoC7, still it doesn't shows like you

Comment: no it isn't working. did you check my code ? is your code matching mine ? please help me

Comment: I run your code on my machine and it is completely working fine.

Comment: hi this was needed, new StringTokenizer(line, "\t"), works fine now all my data's are separated, do you know how can i edit my cell's in table and update it

Comment: I don't know why this is not working for you. To table cell editable  use table.setCellEditable(true).

Comment: hi ya i have done that, but now this is my new error hope you can help me with ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056222/update-the-jtable-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) to represent the data in your table? It will take care of all the Swing-related stuff for you, and you can easily add columns or rows to it, using `addColumn(Object)` and `addRow(Object[])`, respectively.

First, you would create a `DefaultTableModel` object.

Then, instead of doing creating a `Vector columns`, you'd just fill the `model` by doing

```
model.addColumn(st1.nextToken()); // (for adding a column)
```

or

```
Vector row = new Vector();
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
    row.add(st2.nextToken());
}
result.addRow(row); // for adding a row
```

Comment: can you give an example i am new to java

Answer (score 0):

Try this If you are using NetBean, where you can bind List of Object to table and Bind Column with respective value **empMList** is list of Employee.

```
org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, empMList, jTable1);
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${address}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Address");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${name}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Employee Name");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding.setEditable(false);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
```